# Targeting element by parent-child path in XSD

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath, xsd

Hi so I'm working on automating truncation of values in an XML related to an XSD.

My though was to somehow extract the "path" of each element in my XML so to speak, and then use it to find each "maxValue" element and attribute value in my XSD, to then in turn truncate each corresponding element value in my XML.

I have managed to just find the values using XPath using the "name" attribute to find the elements and their "maxValues" in my XSD, but in some cases there are elements with the same name across different complexTypes.

What I'm trying to achieve as a dynamic method which has the xml and xsd as input parameters.

To show you what I mean I've drastically minimized the content:

So here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<updateProduct>
    <product>
        <brand>NameOfBrand</brand>
        <externalSystemId>11000011</externalSystemId>
        <modelId>10000001</modelId>
        <request>
            <createdBy>John Doe, Jane Doe, Jack Doe, Doe John, Doe Jane, Doe Jack</createdBy>
            <createdDate>2021-01-01T00:00:00</createdDate>
            <origin>Application</origin>
            <id>12345678</id>
            <attachment>
                <attachmentPath>.\PictureFile</attachmentPath>
            </attachment>
        </request>
    </product>
</updateProduct>
```

and here is my XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="updateProduct" type="updateProductType"/>

  <xs:complexType name="productType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="createdBy" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"><xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="xs:string"><xs:maxLength value="128"/></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element>
        <xs:element type="requestType" name="request" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>


  <xs:complexType name="modelType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="createdBy" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"><xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="xs:string"><xs:maxLength value="64"/></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element>   
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  
  
  <xs:complexType name="requestType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="createdBy" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"><xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="xs:string"><xs:maxLength value="32"/></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>


  <xs:complexType name="updateProductType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="productType" name="product" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

So Lets say I want to truncate the the value of "createdBy" in the "request" element in my XML.
What I want to to is to find the "maxLength" value for "createdBy" in:

```
updateProduct\\product\\request\\createdBy
```

I've managed to extract all element paths from the xml, just as the one shown above, and then tried to access the maxValue for that specific element in my XSD by using XPath.

I though it would work with something like:

```
//*[@name='updateProduct']//*[@name='product']//*[@name='request']//*[@name='createdBy']
```

Or somethin to that effect...

But as you can see it's not as straight forward as traversing through a path in XML when doing it against an XSD, as the elements in the XSD defines relationships differently. Some times the name attribute equals the "typeName" depending on what tier and what type of element it is. Other times the child nodes are between the parent element and a sequence element which breaks the traversing I guess, and so on.

Am I reinventing the wheel here maybe?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing source XSD schema documents to extract information is extremely difficult in the general case, unless you constrain the schema documents to use a small subset of the XSD language.

It's much better to use an API to access a compiled schema produced by a schema processor.

In Saxon [disclaimer: my company's product, and other solutions may be available] I would recommend making your stylesheet schema-aware so you are accessing typed data, and then using the extension function `saxon:type($e)` to get the type of an element $e, which is a reference to the complex or simple type in the schema that was used to validate the element. If that type has a `maxLength` facet then you will be able to find its value using the XPath expression `saxon:type($e)("facets")[.("class")="maxLength"]("value")`.

Not tested.

Comment: I understand, well as i'm not the one owning the decision economically i unfortunately have to roll back to my previous idea which is to have a mapping-metadata file where i manually fill the length or each property to be mapped and read the values from there. I guess i'll have to skip this until i find a better way.

Thanks for your time to answer Michael. :)